# Are there any tricks to solving this sum?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, summation, problem-solving

Suppose that I have a generic, real function $f(x)$ where $x$ is a positive integer. Suppose further that
$$\sum_{i=1}^{x} f(i)=B(x),$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^{x} \Phi_i=A,$$
for some $\Phi_i>0$, where $A>0$ is constant and $B(x)$ is a positive function. My question is this: How do I solve the sum
\begin{equation} \label{a}
\sum_{i=1}^{x} \Phi_if(i) 
\end{equation}
to leading error? I know that the sum itself can not be solved analytically unless all the $\Phi_i$ are known, which they aren't. So my hope is to find a solution of the form $\sum_{i=1}^{x} \Phi_if(i)=g(B(x),A)+ O(\cdots),$ where $g$ is a function and the $O$-symbol is big-$O$ notation. My guess is that $$g(B(x), A)=\frac{A}{x} B(x),$$ but I am struggling to find the correspond $O(\cdots)$. I would consult literature for this if I knew what to ask, but I am not even sure what field of mathematics this falls under. If anyone has any ideas on how to solve the problem or on literature that may lead me in the right direction, I would appreciate it.

Comment: How is the sum over $\Phi$ equal to an $x$ independent constant? all are the $\Phi$ equal to zero? Or did you mean this only for sufficiently large $x$?

Comment: @Sal Thank you for catching this. It would be more appropriate to use $\Phi_i$ rather than $\Phi(i)$. This question has been changed accordingly

Comment: Please change the title

Comment: @asdfglill I still don't understand how the sum up to $x$ can be an $x$ independent constant unless either all the $\Phi_i$ vanish or this is only true for some large $x$